# Code doesn't work when inside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that works well when used outside a function. But not sure what goes wrong when I just wrap a function around it.

This is my working code: Idea is to move the pencil in a square path. In the working code, it follows the square path but when I wrap around the function, it keeps going on in a straight line.

```
var direction ='right';
var angle = 0;
var sum_angle = 0;

    for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
      if(--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop.";
      move_draw_Player(direction, 100);
      var new_angle=90;
      $('#player').animate({rotate: '90deg'}, 100);
      var angle=angle +new_angle;
      sum_angle =sum_angle + angle;
    }

    function move_draw_Player(directionStr, amount) {
                directionStr =angle;
                  var x = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/-180) * amount;
                  var y = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/-180) * amount;
                  z= amount/100;
           $('#pencil').animate({'left': '-='+x+'px', 'top': '-='+y+'px'}, z*350, 'linear', function() {
            //window.counter = window.counter +2;
            pen.moveTo((pencil.offset().left - cw.offset().left),(pencil.offset().top+ pencil.height() -ac.offset().top)); 
      });
```

But when I wrap a function around it, it doesn't work. What could be going wrong?

```
var direction ='right';
var angle = 0;
var sum_angle = 0;
   function Draw_Square() {
            for (var count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
              if(--window.LoopTrap == 0) throw "Infinite loop.";
              move_draw_Player(direction, 100);
              var new_angle=90;
              $('#player').animate({rotate: '90deg'}, 100);
              var angle=angle +new_angle;
              sum_angle =sum_angle + angle;
            }

            }

            function move_draw_Player(directionStr, amount) {


                        directionStr =angle;
                          var x = Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/-180) * amount;
                          var y = Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/-180) * amount;
                          z= amount/100;
                   $('#pencil').animate({'left': '-='+x+'px', 'top': '-='+y+'px'}, z*350, 'linear', function() {
                    //window.counter = window.counter +2;
                    pen.moveTo((pencil.offset().left - cw.offset().left),(pencil.offset().top+ pencil.height() -ac.offset().top));
              });
    }

    //}

    Draw_Square();
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Or doesn't the code execute? Where do you define ```direction```?

Comment: your brackets seem to be misplaced. Also where do you define amount? And you're adding angle to new_angle while declaring angle (are you redeclaring it by accident, or should that be sum_angle?)?  I see a few issues.

Comment: `var angle=angle + new_angle;` gives NaN - how does this code work at all?

Comment: I *suspect* it's a scope issue - but hard to tell. Perhaps you could create a snippet (`[{}]` button) with enough code to *demonstrate* the problem.  Have a read of [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the question. Idea is to move pencil in a square path. In the working code, it makes square but in the function, it just goes straight- doesn't turn by 90.